# Unable to load-balance with nginx

Tags: nginx

On my host machine I have three instances of one web-service - they run on ports 32826, 32827 and 32828. So that when I go to 127.0.0.1:32826 or 127.0.0.1:32827 or 127.0.0.1:32828, I see in browser a nice web-page.

Besides, I have nginx running on the same host. Now I want it to load-balance between these three instances. I did it like so:

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    sendfile on;

    upstream app_servers {

        server 127.0.0.1:32826;

        server 127.0.0.1:32827;

        server 127.0.0.1:32828;

    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        root /code;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri/ $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
             proxy_pass http://app_servers;
             proxy_redirect off;
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

    }
}
```

I put this configuration into '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf' and restarted nginx. When however I go to `127.0.0.1`, I just see a default welcoming nginx page. I'm not sure what I did wrong and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting your reverse proxy config under wrong location block.

Try / location block.

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    sendfile on;

upstream app_servers {

    server 127.0.0.1:32826;

    server 127.0.0.1:32827;

    server 127.0.0.1:32828;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    root /code;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://app_servers;
         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    #location ~ \.php$ {
         #proxy_pass http://app_servers;
         #proxy_redirect off;
         #proxy_set_header Host $host;
         #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    #}

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this question while troubleshooting my own problem with the same symptoms, but discovered a different solution. 
With the default install on CentOS using the yum repositories, nginx.conf contains

> include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf

which I believe was overriding my configuration in nginx.conf. After commenting (or completely removing) this include statement and restarting nginx, load balancing worked as expected.